# how to pass two instances of a namespace to a plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know with the heading of the question it does not make sense, here is the problem: 
As you can see in the following scenario, I am calling generateMenu function twice in a page with different parameters say

1. generateMenu(selector1,data1);
2. generateMenu(selector2,data2);

But because of the following implementation

```
MyContextNameSpace.helpers.dataBind = data;
```

is getting overriden by second call say data2. 
Any suggestion how to correct my code so that it should work for both calls

```
MyContextNameSpace.helpers = {
menuItems: [{
            textKey: 'printChart',
            onclick: function () {

            }
        },  {
            separator: true
        },{
            textKey: 'downloadPNG',
            onclick: function () {
                $(this).contextMenu();
            }
        },{
            textKey: 'downloadCSV',
            onclick:function(){
                $(this).exportCSV({
                    data:MyContextNameSpace.helpers.dataBind
                });
            }
        }],
}

function generateMenu(selector,data){ 
 MyContextNameSpace.helpers.dataBind = data;
for(x in MyContextNameSpace.helpers.menuItems ){
    if(MyContextNameSpace.helpers.menuItems[x].separator){
        penserContextMenuChild.append('<hr style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">')
    }
    else{
        var obj = new Object();
        var obj = $("<div />",{
            click:MyContextNameSpace.helpers.menuItems[x].onclick,
            css:{
               'cursor' : 'pointer',
               'padding' : '0px 10px',
               'color' : 'rgb(48, 48, 48)',
                'font-size':'11px',
                'background':'none'
            },
            text:MyContextNameSpace.helpers.menuItems[x].textKey
        })
        penserContextMenuChild.append(obj);
    }

   // console.log(MyContextNameSpace.helpers.menuItems[x].textKey)
}
}
```

Comment: You should use classes and make instances of each menu, to configure them separately

Comment: can you please elaborate by some simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple class to holds all properties of menu

**Menu**

```
var Menu = function(selector, options) {
   this.selector = selector;
   this.options = options || {};
   this.data = this.options.data || [];
   this.children = [] /*  */;
};
```

and add a render method for example, to loop over `menuItems` passed in options, and create DOM element for each item

```
Menu.prototype.render = function() {
   var that = this,
       children = that.children,
       menuItems = that.options.menuItems || [],
       i,
       length,
       menuItem,
       $el
   ;

   for(i = 0, length = menuItems.length ; i < length ; i++) {
       menuItem = menuItems[i];

       if(menuItem.separator) {
          $el = $('<hr style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">');
       } else {
          $el = $('<div />', {
             click: menuItem.onclick,
             css: {
               'cursor' : 'pointer',
               'padding' : '0px 10px',
               'color' : 'rgb(48, 48, 48)',
                'font-size':'11px',
                'background':'none'
             },
             text: menuItem.textKey
          });
       }

       children.push($el);
   }

   // Render children array in the appropriate selector passed upon creation 
   $(that.selector).append(children);
};
```

Finally, create any number of menus (instances) without touching `data` of other menus

**Menu1**

```
var menu1 = new Menu('#div1', {
   data: [],
   menuItems: [
     {
       textKey: 'printChart'
      },
     {
       separator: true
     },{
       textKey: 'downloadPNG',
       onclick: function () {
         $(this).contextMenu();
       }
     },{
       textKey: 'downloadCSV',
       onclick:function(){
          $(this).exportCSV({
            data: menu1.data
          });
       }
    }]
});

menu1.render();
```

**Menu2**

```
var menu2 = new Menu('#div2', {
   data: [],
   menuItems: [
     {
       textKey: 'printChart'
      },
     {
       separator: true
     },{
       textKey: 'downloadPNG',
       onclick: function () {
         $(this).contextMenu();
       }
     },{
       textKey: 'downloadCSV',
       onclick:function(){
          $(this).exportCSV({
            data: menu2.data
          });
       }
    }]
});

menu2.render();
```

See running [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/daposucape/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I modified the code a bit but thanks for the solution :) . Its working fine